# Kafka consumer configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How to configure the consumer so that it will poll 50 records at a time in single poll.
I have created the consumer with max_poll_records is set to  50. But my consumer is consuming single record at time.how to configure the consumer so that it will fetch 50 records in the single poll.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `max.poll.records`, the consumer returns at-most the configured maximum number of records. Say, if your topic contains 1000 unread records and `max.poll.records` is set to 50, then the consumer will return only 50 records in each `poll` call. But, if your topics contains only 5 unread records, it will return the 5 records immediately.

If you want to process the records in a batch, then you may have to accumulate the records in a list, then process it once the size reaches. Note: You have to disable the auto commit and should commit manually once you processed all the 50 records.